# html div tag id

Tags: jquery, html

I have two buttons in my webpage. If first button is clicked, Google map should be loaded inside a div. This can be easily done by giving the id of the Google map in the div as follows.

```
 <div id="map" />
```

Now I have another `<div>` element above this; if the second button is clicked, this div should be loaded in the same place of the previous. How do I do this?

```
<div id="table" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to load new content into a DIV or do you just want to show content in the same place?

If you want to reload content you'd have to use something like AJAX to get the job done. If you just want to create a 'tab' like effect just use CSS's pseudo-class elements. You can find more information about both those things on CSS-Tricks.com

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery like

Show

```
 $('.target').show();
```

Hide

```
$('.target').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to store the previous value on the first button click.

Comment: in the second button click i want to load some other map not same map.but it should be loaded on the same position as previous.so two div id and two button click.But position is same.Div should change its content with respect to the id from the button click..